# GCC Initializing and using graphics on a bare bones linux kernel

Tags: c, linux, gcc, graphics

Been looking online for several days now and keep seeing SDL and a few other packages as solutions for someone trying to do graphics on a linux system with GCC.

I state GCC as G++ does not work on this Helios SBC Device I am currently developing for.

Secondly the Helios SBC has a Flash Memory Chip that the OS and everything is supposed to reside on. This Flash Memory chip is 256mb in size, Yes I said 256(Yes I know there is memory sticks bigger than this.. but this is what I got to work with).

I finally got the hardware put together and the system firing up and proceeded to start setting up the display portions of the application and purpose to this Helios SBC is being used for, (the Analog Data Acquisition and Device Calibration will come later)

I simply wanted to set an image, png tiff what have you and push it to the screen with GCC and have not found where I would be able to do it without downloading and installing add ons or other libraries.

This is of great concern as space is a huge issue and I dont want to give up more of the remaining 70 mb of space on the flashdisk to huge libraries that would essentially be better replaced with something smaller leaner and able to push image files and draw a line and dot.. that would be the extent of what I have to do.

Comment: The abreviation GCC stands for GNU Compiler Collection, meaning that GCC includes both the C compiler gcc and the C++ compiler g++.

Comment: As for your problem, it has nothing to do with the compiler, and is completely platform dependent. Though there are cross-platform libraries (like SDL 1, don't know about SDL 2) that can be used for non-X solutions.

Comment: More related to your problem, there are many Linux distributions for memory constrained platforms, which can even run X. Remember that it wasn't that many years ago that 128MB RAM was considered quite a lot, and Linux is known to be able to run on very old (and with few resources compared to todays (or even yesterdays) computers) systems.

Comment: Do you have a framebuffer device, like `/dev/fb0`?  If so, it's as easy as opening that and writing to it.  E.g., as root:  `head -n 1024 /dev/urandom > /dev/fb0`.  If you have an X server running, you need to use the X APIs to write to the screen.

Comment: not 100% sure about the /dev/fb0 but I think there is such a creature in all the things going on in there Indiv,

I saw the SDL packages was kind of hoping there was something native that I forgot or was missing. 

Thanks for the info guys

Comment: oh yea, this Helios SBC system does not have G++ (tried compiling a couple applications with the g++ start off ie when I was testing I ran the hello.c standard test using c++ but it failed miserably, std was not recognized, etc hence my statement GCC not G++ (Yes i was initially baffled by this as well as most linux distros have both)